# When open url in new window using target blank before open it shows about:blank

Tags: html

when i opened the site in new window via target blank before opening it shows in url about:blank

Please suggest how to remove this.

```
<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">click here</a>
```

Comment: Can yous show us your code ?

Comment: see above i have update the question

Comment: Does it later redirect to google.com?

Comment: yes but when it is opening it show in url about:blank first them open the google

Comment: its default feature when we user target blank it first shows about:blank then opening the url but i want to change the about:blank or remove this

Comment: Which browser do you use ? did you try on another browser ?

Comment: @PiyushDhanotiya it is not that default. I am not getting about:blank it just redirects me to google.google chrome is the browser I am using

Comment: the problem which i am facing on mozilla browser..

Comment: @PiyushDhanotiya - the browser is structured in this way. Side code can not be changed

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">click here</a>
```

Comment: he should use http or // to open a url. otherwise browser will treat as sub directory

Comment: its not wrong its correct. but not fit with his question . @PiyushDhanotiya : that is firefox default features. you can't change that. there may be any option in firefox settings but it will not usefull as you can't expect your users will have the same setting.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to write http:// in front of the www.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">click here</a>
```